# script/generate migration throws error about I18n in Rails 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this on line 56 in my environment.rb:

```
I18n.load_path += Dir[ File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'lib', 'locale', '*.{rb,yml}') ]
```

I can run the app just fine, but when I try to run:
script/generate migration

I get this error:

```
environment.rb:56: uninitialized constant I18n (NameError)
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `active_support` (where the `I18n` module is located) is not loaded in your `environment.rb`.  The proper way to add directories to your i18n load path is by the following in your `environment.rb`:

```
config.i18n.load_path << Dir[File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

I think, as an alternative, you might be able to throw in a `require 'active_support'` before your reference to the `I18n` module in your `environment.rb`, but it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The line I used was copy/pasted bad code from a tutorial.

So by using

```
config.i18n.load_path
```

instead of

```
I18n.load_path
```

I got rid of the error.